# Selecting Set Data From Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, field

I have set up a table where one of the fields is a set type – set(‘1’,’2’,’3’,’4’,’5’).

Is there a way to pull that set type data down into a form on a web page – much like you would do with say updating a record where you run a query to select certain data from a table and pull that down into your update form. But, instead of pulling down the data inserted – can you pull the set type data inputted when the field was set up?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to query the information_schema tables, then parse the field with PHP (which IMHO should be trivial)

```
SELECT column_type 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database' 
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'your_table' 
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'your_column'
```

The result should be something like: set(‘1’,’2’,’3’,’4’,’5’)

Answer (score -1):

Although he writes specifically about `ENUM`, Chris Komlenic's article [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/) is equally applicable to `SET`.  In particular:

> **4. Getting a list of distinct ENUM members is a pain.**
>
> > A very common need is to populate a select-box or drop down list with possible values from the database. Like this:
> >
> > Select color:
> >
> > `[ select box ]`
> >
> > If these values are stored in a reference table named 'colors', all you need is: `SELECT * FROM colors` ...which can then be parsed out to dynamically generate the drop down list. You can add or change the colors in the reference table, and your sexy order forms will automatically be updated. Awesome.
> >
> > Now consider the evil ENUM: how do you extract the member list? You could query the ENUM column in your table for DISTINCT values but that will only return values that are actually *used and present in the table*, not necessarily all possible values. You can query INFORMATION_SCHEMA and parse them out of the query result with a scripting language, but that's unnecessarily complicated. In fact, I don't know of any elegant, purely SQL way to extract the member list of an ENUM column.

Comment: Good insight but this never answered the question

Comment: @AgRizzo: The final paragraph of the quote describes exactly the solution you have demonstrated in your answer.  There is no requirement to demonstrate code in answers on SO, least of all when the OP has shown no code in his question and the requested solution is strongly discouraged.  Please remove your downvote.

Comment: I will if (1) you edit yours {I can't change my vote until you edit your answer} AND (2) copy my code into your answer as example code.  I will delete my answer, upvote yours.  Until then, your answer, while lengthy is no better IMO than 'Yes, it can.' I cannot believe OP would ask this question AND know what the information_schema tables are.  So, while adding the code is beyond their request, I don't feel it is extraneous

Comment: @AgRizzo: You miss the overriding point that using information schema in this way is "*unnecessarily complicated*" and that one should actually store the sets in a separate association table.

Comment: I don't think I'm missing the point. My goal is to help OP. The OP has a problem: they have a table and need to get these values. _They need help getting those values._ Your answer helps them understand the weakness of their design. I agree: their design is not ideal, but they are asking for help to get the values, not for a criticism of their table design. I looked at your post and felt it didn't help the OP with their specific question.